# Subfolders and files ignored when copying from sdcard to PC through USB

Tags: usb, sd-card, file-transfer, windows

So I have a music folder that I'm trying to copy from my sdcard onto my PC using Windows Explorer. For some reason, when I attempt to do this, it 'completes' really quickly and I only end up with a few folders inside the main folder that are missing most, if not all of their contents as well. The weird thing is if I go into all of these individual subfolders and copy them one by one, it works fine.

Anybody know what's going on, and what I can possibly do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I just needed to wait a little longer for the "Copying..." dialog to pop up again. Windows is weird sometimes.